# Linq query to order list by occurences of foreign key in another list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have two classes, Profile and Download. Download has the foreign key ProfileID which maps to the ID in Profile. Each row in Download represents one download for the connected profile.

I'm having trouble making a linq query that fetches a list of Profiles that is ordered in how many times it has been downloaded.

EDIT:
Here's what I have so far in the function.

```
    IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel();
    model.NewSubtitles = (from Profile in _ProfileRepo.GetAll()
                      orderby Profile.ID descending
                      select Profile).Take(5).ToList();

    // This doesn't work:
    // model.TopSubtitles = (from n in _ProfileRepo.GetAll()
    //                       join d in _DownloadRepo.GetAll() on n.ID equals d.ProfileID into c
    //                       group c by c.ProfileID into g
    //                       orderby g.Count() descending
    //                       select n).Take(5).ToList();

        return View(model);
```

Comment: Do you have any code already prepared we can have a look at?

Comment: I added it to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
     model.NewSubtitles = (from Profile in _ProfileRepo.GetAll()
                  join downloads in _DownloadRepo.GetAll() on Profile.UserId equals downloads.UserId
                 group downloads by Profile into p
                  orderby p.Count() descending
                  select new {p.Key.UserId , p.Key.UserName , p.Count()).Take(5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like :

```
from d in Downloads
orderby d.Profiles.Count()
...
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Should do what you want:

```
model.TopSubtitles =  (from p in _ProfileRepo.GetAll()
                      join d in _DownloadRepo.GetAll() on p.ID equals d.ProfileId
                      group d by p into g
                      orderby g.Count() descending
                      select g.Key).Take(5).ToList();
```

and for the LINQ syntax challenged:

```
model.TopSubtitles = _ProfileRepo.GetAll()
  .Join(_DownloadRepo.GetAll(), p => p.ID, d => d.ProfileId, (p, d) => new { Profile = p, Download = d })
  .GroupBy(x => x.Profile)
  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
  .Select (g => g.Key)
  .Take(5)
  .ToList();
```